# Can't interact with JFileChooser window, not clickable or closeble

Tags: java

In my code I am asking the user to choose an image. My JFileChooser window worked fine. Then I restarted my computer and now whenever that window comes up it is not clickable in any way. I can't open a file, I can't cancel, I can't chooser folders or files. Here is the necessary code.

```
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "jpeg");
    jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    jfc.setVisible(true);
    int ret = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (ret == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        return;
    }
    File file_1 = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    file_path = file_1.getAbsolutePath();
```

Breakpoints show that the program never leaves this line:

```
    int ret = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
```

As I said the same exact code was working fine moments ago. Not sure what is causing this situation.

In my main program I click "Add image" which calls the previously mentioned code. I try clicking on the window "Open" opened by "showOpenDialog" but it doesn't matter where I click. Nothing changes. The main program resumes once I close the "Open" window from my task manager. Also in my task manager "Open" window doesn't say not responding, it looks fine and closes at an instance and furthermore inside the text field the text cursor is blinking.

EDIT: Same exact code works on a separate project that consists of only this code.

EDIT 2: Some additional codes.

Here is the complete load_file() function.

```
public class Image {
private static String file_path;
private static ImageFrame frame;
public static boolean isImgLoaded = false;
public static void load_file(){ 
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "jpeg");
    jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    jfc.setVisible(true);
    int ret = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (ret == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        return;
    }
    File file_1 = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    file_path = file_1.getAbsolutePath();
    ImageFrame frm = new ImageFrame();
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frame = frm;
    isImgLoaded = frame.get_component().is_img_loaded();
    frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            closeFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the button code that calls the function when pressed. shlErgo is my shell that the UI is built on.

```
    Button btnAddImage = new Button(shlErgo, SWT.NONE);
    btnAddImage.setBounds(230, 10, 75, 25);
    btnAddImage.setText("Add Image");
    btnAddImage.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if (!Image.isImgLoaded){
                Image.load_file();
            }
            else{
                Error.translate(2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your program on a different machine?

Comment: Maybe your hard drive has a defect? That would explain the freeze when the dialog tries to show folder contents. You can set a different initial path with ``jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/my/path"))``

Comment: Do not do a `setVisible` on the file chooser window.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I have tried setting a different path, it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @SebastianS Haven't tried it on a different machine yet. I might end up giving it a try but I'm at work so it might take a bit of time.

Comment: @KDM I'm afraid it didn't resolve the issue. I already tried commenting and uncommenting every combination of the piece of code I shared here. I'm starting to think the issue is either with my JVM, Eclipse or my hard drive as previously mentioned.

Comment: @GoktugO: Did you try a simple program only with this code? What happens?

Comment: @KDM it works as it should. But in my project it fails. I haven't posted the rest of the project because I thought it was unrelated. And according to my knowledge it should be, as I literally only call this function from my project as a static function. (I've tried an unstatic version as well). Everything else happens in this function. Also as I mentioned the program gets stuck at the "showOpenDialog" line.

Comment: @GoktugO: The only reason I can think of is that the EDT is somehow deadlocked. Can you post the code from your project that invokes this part of the code?

Comment: @KDM I edited the main post with the code you requested.

Comment: @GoktugO: you are mixing up swing and SWT. I am sure SWT has a filechooser component. You should be using that.

Comment: A quick link https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_prompt_the_user_to_select_a_file_or_a_directory%3F

Comment: @KDM A coworker suggested that as well, so I wrote a similar code using the FileDialog and it got stuck exactly the same way. I checked the new FileDialog version on a seperate program as well and once again it was working. So I think I am going to be we writing the project from the start. This time I won't mix swing and SWT together even though I don't think that was the issue because my code was working at one point despite being a mix of the two. So I am accepting the defeat against this problem, thank you for all the help.